# invalid column name sql drop down list

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a drop down list that will be populated with the data from an online database; however, every time I run it it keeps giving me the error message

> "Invalid column 'First Name' ".

I have tried putting a space between and it still doesn't work. The column name on the database is **'First Name'**. Please advise.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ExtNumber, FirstName, LastName from Extensions", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "First Name";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Ext Number";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: use ` to enclose the column name in the select statement

Comment: "First Name" <> "FirstName"

Comment: Your SqlCommand` shows that `FirstName` does not have a space in it.  In your `DataTextField` you have a space.

Answer (score 2):

My friend, the ideea is that if you have spaces in column names, they must be enclosed in [] brackets.

So, your code must be changed to look like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [Ext Number], [First Name], LastName       from Extensions", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "First Name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Ext Number";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Invalid column is clearly an SQL error. If the man says that "The column name on the database is 'First Name'" what other problem could it be?

Comment: Upon further review, I missed the part of the question where he specified the name of the column.  Sorry about that.  If you edit your answer (add white space or something) I'll be able to change my vote.

Comment: I'm able to connect to it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your query:

> "Select ExtNumber, [First Name], LastName from Extensions"

with the [] (brackets)  in "First Name" (with the blank space)

Comment: @DanBracuk I'll appreciate if you could give some recommendations to Sanchez about his problem, cause clearly, for you, what I said is out of topic.

Comment: The comments to the question from Kritner and Martin Parkin give sufficient guidance.

Comment: Upon further review, I missed the part of the question where he specified the name of the column.  Sorry about that.  If you edit your answer (add white space or something) I'll be able to change my vote.

Comment: Don't worry. That is the reason why I send a text editing to Sanchez. To make it clearer. I hope that he can fix this problem.